# How to access jQuery draggable's helper element inside the drag callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable with a custom helper function defined like this:

```
$("article.post").draggable({     
  helper: function(e) {
    // return a dom element
  },
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    var helper = $this.draggable( "option", "helper" );
    // helper is not the returned dom element, but the function definition
  }
});
```

In the drag callback, I want to access the helper element returned by the function, but `$this.draggable( "option", "helper" )` returns the function definition instead.

Is there a way to access the helper element?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it turns out it is accessible via `ui.helper`.